# How to initialise class in the require statement? (typescript)

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

How does a basic class export need to look like so when required, it can be initialised like this:

```
const api = require('myapi')('key_...');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you're wanting to the `myapi` module to instantiate a class (ie `BasicClass`) and return this via a function that is the default export. One way to achieve that in TypeScript is via the following:

```
/* The myapi module */

/* The "basic class" that will be instantiated when default export function is called */
class BasicClass {
    constructor(key:string) {
        console.log(`Constructor got key: ${key}`)
    }
}

/* The default module export is a function that accepts a key string argument */
module.exports = (key:string) => {

    /* The function returns an instance of BasicClass */
    return new BasicClass(key)
}
```

The `myapi` module could then be used as follows:

```
const api = require('myapi')('key_...');

/* api is instance of BasicClass */
```

Hope that helps

Comment: getting TypeError: require(...) is not a function

Comment: i guess the point was to have it on one statement...

this seems to work:

const api = (key: string) => {
 return new BasicClass(key)
}

module.exports = api;

Comment: Yes that's also an option - you can condense the `myapi` module down a little by defining the arrow function directly on `module.exports` as shown in the updated answer

Comment: thanks! (i added a return type so I can get IntelliSense as well, but all the rest is great)

Comment: taking advantage of OP here :) but if BasicClass had an argument that was basically importing some functions from another file, how can I use the key in the external file

(https://jsfiddle.net/rdspqek1/)